# how to post id in current URL using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, html-lists, sendkeys

I am learning j query and i want to send id in current URL then UL Li on click event to send id in current URL without page refresh

**like this:**

```
Current URL = localhost/backupapp-latest-21-05/index.php?r=site/Application<br>
send id url = localhost/backupapp-latest-21-05/index.php?r=site/Application&abcid=48
```

there is a **abcid=48** is my UL Li id

try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#hari-ul > li').each(function(index, element) {

      $(element).click(function(e) {
         var id = (this.id);
         window.location.href  = "index.php?r=site/Application&abcid="+id;

      }
    });
  });
});
```

this code send id in URL but page refresh and  i want id without page refresh

Comment: you have an extra `}` in your code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Check the examples here:

[Check here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Or try this way :

```
$.get('path/to/yourfile.html', function(data) {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: i already try this code but its con not running in my j query i want ot another example j query code